# 2d physics ball bouncing and rolling on incline response

Tags: 2d, response, physics, collision

I asked this question before but it got closed because it said I was asking for recommendations which isn't allowed.
Really I'm just looking for a solution whether it's from a book,website or someone who knows how to do this.
I progressed somewhat since I asked the question the last time, but anyways:

So far I've got a program where you can spawn balls which can collide with other balls and bounce off the window boundaries just fine, you can also draw a linestrip (am using sfml as I'm just a beginner and it requires very little setting up before you can get going with coding), so you hold down the mouse and every however many pixels it'll set the line you're currently drawing and start a new one at the end, so I can either do straight edges or change the setting to make a new line every pixel and make very ugly curves with the mouse (need to figure out how to do splines).
It makes no difference for the collision as it finds the closest point on the line every frame.
So dropping the ball onto the incline is fine, it bounces off like it should, or even several times,
but getting it to roll is a different story, even if you start the ball on the incline with 0 velocity as soon as it starts colliding it gets sent up off the incline instead of moving along it, and starts doing tiny bounces.
The only solution I found, which is terrible, is to time each bounce (or height of bounce I guess) and when its low enough to stop it bouncing and only have gravity act on it.
I'd be happy with it except what happens is it will bounce lower and lower until it reaches the
threshold, at which point it visibly slows down before it starts accelerating again rolling down the incline, which looks really bad, like it comes to a halt and starts getting pulled along.
Ideally I'd like it to actually simulate the physical forces  rather than having to resort to tricks like timing the bounces.

While I was writing this I put in some code to work out what the angle is that the ball hits the incline at and I think the problem lies there, it's fine if it hits it from free fall but when rolling the angle shows as about 67-72 degrees when it should be..0 i guess?

Any help appreciated.
Here's the code for the collision.

```
void Particle::collideRamp(sf::Vector2f cp,sf::Vector2f l1,sf::Vector2f l2) {
    //distance between ball and closest point on line
    float dx = x - cp.x;
    float dy = y - cp.y;
    float distance = hypot(dx, dy);

//find line normal
    float lx = l2.x - l1.x;
    float ly = l2.y - l1.y;
    sf::Vector2f LineNormal = normalize(ly, -lx);

//make velocity and projection same length so can mirror velocity against normal

    sf::Vector2f normalMag(velocity.x * LineNormal.x,velocity.y * LineNormal.y);
    sf::Vector2f Projection = LineNormal * hypotf(normalMag.x, normalMag.y);
    sf::Vector2f vel = normalize(velocity.x, velocity.y) * hypotf(normalMag.x, normalMag.y);


//working on making circles rotate but early days
    float rsx = prevx - x;
    float rsy = prevy - y;
    float rSpeed = hypot(rsx, rsy) / circumference;
    
//work out gravity forces for the incline, sin@mg down incline etc.
    sf::Vector2f gravPerpendicular = normalize(-ly, lx);
    sf::Vector2f gravParallell = normalize(lx, ly);
    
    float gravPerMag;
    float gravParMag;

    
        gravParMag = sin(M_halfPI + atan2f(gravParallell.x,gravParallell.y));
        gravPerMag = cos(M_halfPI + atan2f(gravParallell.x,gravParallell.y));

//// Collision detected.
    if (distance < (radius)) {

//work out angle the ball struck the incline
        float iAngle = atan2f(lx, ly) + atan2f(velocity.x, velocity.y);
        //cout << iAngle * 180 / M_PI << " aft " << endl;
//make sure its 0-90
        if (iAngle > 1.5708)
            iAngle = 1.5708 - (iAngle - 1.5708);

//move the ball back if it went past the line by the amount it passed it by
        sf::Vector2f v = normalize(velocity.x + forceAcc.x, velocity.y + forceAcc.y);

        float overlap = (radius - distance );
        x -= v.x * overlap;
        y -= v.y * overlap;


        rotationSpeed = rSpeed;

//messing with changing the angle only if bounce is a certain height as this is what's causing the 
//problem i think, however the ball slows down before it starts rolling making it look weird
        if (collClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 0.01) {
            
            sf::Vector2f newVel = ((velocity + Projection) + Projection);
            
            forceAcc = newVel;
            float e = elasticity * elasticity;
            forceAcc *= e;
            velocity = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
            

        }
        
//add gravity forces, since the force that goes along the line normal is cancelled out 
//by an equal force from the line I guess it doesn't need to be added?

        //accelerateI(sf::Vector2f(-sin(gravPerpendicular) * gravPerMag * gravity * mass, cos(gravPerpendicular) * gravPerMag * gravity * mass));

        //accelerate(sf::Vector2f(sin(gravPerpendicular) * gravPerMag * gravity * mass, -cos(gravPerpendicular) * gravPerMag * gravity * mass));

//this one rolls it down the incline
        accelerateI(sf::Vector2f(gravParallell.x * gravParMag * gravity * mass, gravParallell.y * gravParMag * gravity * mass ));

//trying wether subtracting gravity helps
        //accelerateI(sf::Vector2f(0, -1 * gravity * mass));

//friction
        //accelerateI(sf::Vector2f(gravParallell.x * forceAcc.x *  friction * mass, gravParallell.y * forceAcc.y * friction * mass));
        

        
        collClock.restart();

        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Thanks guys

Comment: If you can phrase your problem more concisely, I think you question will be better received. Preferably include a gif to show the current state.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll get on it